# Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker is hidden within uigrid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am integrating Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker within ui-grid, but i am facing an issue. When the user opens the datepicker by clicking a cell the datepicker is displayed but within ui-grid because of which user cannot see the full calendar and has to scroll.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ67m.png

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear that you are using the datepicker popup instead of the inline datepicker.  So, the first recommendation would be to use datepicker popup.  Second, set the datepicker-append-to-body option to true to get it to attach to the document body rather than the grid cell it's defined in.

Comment: Thanks @Russ for your answer. I added the datepicker-append-to-body and it worked like a charm.